# How to repeat rows in dataframe with each values in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE' : ['2015-12-01', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-02'],
    'DAY_NUMBER' : [3, 3, 4, 4],
    'HOUR' : [5, 6, 5, 6],
    'count' : [12,11,14,15]
})

         DATE  DAY_NUMBER  HOUR  count
0  2015-12-01           3     5     12
1  2015-12-01           3     6     11
2  2015-12-02           4     5     14
3  2015-12-02           4     6     15
```

And I have a list `extra_hours = [1,13]`

I would like to create new rows in which `HOUR` column will be filled from `extra_hours`, and `count=0', and repeat these row creation for each unique`['DATE', 'DAY_NUMBER']`.

My Expected df is as follows.

```
         DATE  DAY_NUMBER  HOUR  count
0  2015-12-01           3     5   12.0
1  2015-12-01           3     6   11.0
2  2015-12-02           4     5   14.0
3  2015-12-02           4     6   15.0
0  2015-12-01           3     1    0.0
0  2015-12-01           3    13    0.0
2  2015-12-02           4     1    0.0
2  2015-12-02           4    13    0.0
```

Now I am creating the dataframe using the below code. I searched a lot, but couldn't find any easier solution. Any help is appreciated to improve the code and performance.

```
extra_df = df[['DATE', 'DAY_NUMBER']].sort_values('DATE').drop_duplicates()
extra_df['HOUR'] = np.array(extra_hours).reshape(1,len(extra_hours)).repeat(extra_df.shape[0], axis=0).tolist()
df.append(extra_df.explode('HOUR'), sort=False).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cross join` with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper `DataFrame` created by `extra_hours` list, last [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original:

```
extra_hours = [1,13]
extra_df = df[['DATE', 'DAY_NUMBER']].sort_values('DATE').drop_duplicates()

extra_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'HOUR':extra_hours, 'count':0, 'tmp':1})

df1 = extra_df.assign(tmp=1).merge(extra_df1, on='tmp').drop('tmp', 1)
extra_df = df.append(df1, sort=True, ignore_index=True)
print (extra_df)
         DATE  DAY_NUMBER  HOUR  count
0  2015-12-01           3     5     12
1  2015-12-01           3     6     11
2  2015-12-02           4     5     14
3  2015-12-02           4     6     15
4  2015-12-01           3     1      0
5  2015-12-01           3    13      0
6  2015-12-02           4     1      0
7  2015-12-02           4    13      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
extra_hours = [1,13]
uniq_dates=df['DATE'].unique()
extra_df = pd.DataFrame({'HOUR':extra_hours, 'count':0})
```

---

```
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([uniq_dates,extra_df.index]),
            columns=['DATE','index']).set_index('index').assign(**extra_df)

final=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
final['DAY_NUMBER']=final['DATE'].map(
    df[['DATE', 'DAY_NUMBER']].drop_duplicates().set_index(['DATE'])['DAY_NUMBER'])
print(final)
```

---

```
         DATE  DAY_NUMBER  HOUR  count
0  2015-12-01           3     5     12
1  2015-12-01           3     6     11
2  2015-12-02           4     5     14
3  2015-12-02           4     6     15
4  2015-12-01           3     1      0
5  2015-12-01           3    13      0
6  2015-12-02           4     1      0
7  2015-12-02           4    13      0
```